# Is there a way to get rid of the error message I created in javascript after the user does the right thing?

Tags: javascript

The code will push a message saying 'First Name Can't be empty', that is when a user clicks on a button before typing their First name. This is great, however, after they get the message, if they do type their first name and submit, the pushed message does not go away!

Is there a way for the pushed message ('First Name Can't be empty') to go away once the user has typed their first name?

Many thanks.

[image]

```js
const name = document.getElementById('FirstName')
const lastName = document.getElementById('LastName')
const email = document.getElementById('EmailAddress')
const password = document.getElementById('Password')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const errorElement1 = document.getElementById('error-FirstName')
const errorElement2 = document.getElementById('error-LastName')
const errorElement3 = document.getElementById('error-Email')
const errorElement4 = document.getElementById('error-Password')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
 let messages = []
 if (name.value === '' || name.value === null) {
  messages.push('First Name Can\'t be empty')
 }

 if (messages.length > 0) {
  e.preventDefault()
  errorElement1.innerText = messages.join(', ')
 }

})
```

Comment: `messages.push('')` is not a good solution as it also runs `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Run an `else` that makes use of `messages.pop()`?

Comment: If there are no errors, doesn't it submit the form and reload the page?

Comment: @Barmar, you are right, the form is submitted and the page reloaded, however, I have added an error message to pop up when the Last Name and other fields are empty. But I would like the error messages to go away as I start typing in the form fields.

Comment: What you really need is an event listener for typing in the input fields that clears the associated error element.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the error element when there are no errors.

```js
const name = document.getElementById('FirstName')
const lastName = document.getElementById('LastName')
const email = document.getElementById('EmailAddress')
const password = document.getElementById('Password')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const errorElement1 = document.getElementById('error-FirstName')
const errorElement2 = document.getElementById('error-LastName')
const errorElement3 = document.getElementById('error-Email')
const errorElement4 = document.getElementById('error-Password')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  let messages = []
  if (name.value === '' || name.value === null) {
    messages.push('First Name Can\'t be empty')
  }

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    errorElement1.innerText = messages.join(', ')
  } else {
    errorElement1.innerText = '';
  }
})
```

Comment: That worked, thanks, it did get rid of the message above the First Name field when I typed in the field and submitted the form, and the other error message were still there if the other fields were empty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just use the innerHTML property of the errorElement after you use a condition to check if the submit has been done correctly

```js
const name = document.getElementById('FirstName')
const lastName = document.getElementById('LastName')
const email = document.getElementById('EmailAddress')
const password = document.getElementById('Password')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const errorElement1 = document.getElementById('error-FirstName')
const errorElement2 = document.getElementById('error-LastName')
const errorElement3 = document.getElementById('error-Email')
const errorElement4 = document.getElementById('error-Password')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
 let messages = []
 if (name.value === '' || name.value === null) {
  messages.push('First Name Can\'t be empty')
 } else {
  //clear messages
  messages = [];
  errorLement1.innerHTML="";
 }

 if (messages.length > 0) {
  e.preventDefault()
  errorElement1.innerText = messages.join(', ')
 }

})
```